# The requested PHP extension ext-mcrypt * is missing from your system

Tags: php5, php.ini, php

I have updated my php to version 5.4.13 etc and well in the terminal my version of php states this

```
   PHP 5.4.12 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2013 21:46:23)
```

But running a composer install io get the following error.

```
  The requested PHP extension ext-mcrypt * is missing from your system
```

Anyway i have tried several emthods to get this to work etc and nothing:

I have used the following: [Solution One](http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server/) and [Solution Two](http://michaelgracie.com/2011/07/21/plugging-mcrypt-into-php-on-mac-os-x-lion-10-7/), they both use a similar approach but i stil ge the errors.

I then did a php info test and this shows that the version is **5.3.15** and that **mycrypt says mcrypt support is enabled**

So is my server using this php and the one in my terminal using another as this what it seems

Any ideas how to fix this?

I am using a MAC Mountain Lion with Mountain Lion Sever (latest), xcode and all operations are up to date and i have restarted the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I simply went back to basics and uninstalled Mac Server and went back to MAMP, this performed all the latest updates and installs required, as my system was conflicting with two separate installs etc

Answer (score 10):

Got the same error in Linux(Ubuntu 14.04)

Check that ini exists

```
/etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
```

If it is so, check that you have symlink to ini.
Something like in directory `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d`

```
05-mcrypt.ini -> ../../mods-available/mcrypt.ini
```

If there is no symlink create it. After installing the `php5-mcrypt` extension I have no symlink, only ini file. That is why create the symlink manualy.

You can use **sudo php5enmod mcrypt** to enable the mod. It will create the symlink for you.

Comment: thanks for the reply on this but in the time i have moved over to Virtual servers mainly using Vagrant and a file call Vaprobash. thanks again

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked in Ubuntu 14.04. May I ask a couple questions: 1. How did you guess there was no .ini file? 2. Why does the php5-mcrypt package not do this automatically? Should I report a bug?

Comment: Also, how did you know it had to be 05-filename, and not some other int at the start?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following solution:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Good luck,

-Iulian

Comment: Can you explain how you might do this without `php5enmod`? Most of us don't have that on our systems.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue - mcrypt showed as installed for CLI but missing via command line. To fix, I ran

```
#php -i
```

to find the location of the command line version's php.ini file and then added

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

After that, running `#php -m` will show you what modules are installed for the command line version and mcrypt should be there. If not, your "Solution 1" and "Solution 2" options should help you build the module - then just make sure the module is installed (or gets copied) to your php installation's module (extension) directory (something like `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/` or check where `extensions_dir` value in php.ini points to).